# no wifi (Samsung galaxy tab 4)

Tags: samsung

I have a brand-new Samsung Galaxy tab for just pulled it out the box it Wi-Fi will not turn on.. the router is "Belkin" have been reading all these answers they keep saying to root and two download different software to buy new hardware it's brand-new why should I have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings > WiFi and check if any network shows 'Connected'.
If not, select the appropriate network and login.

Answer (score 0):

If blue tooth doesn't work either sounds like the radio firmware is corrupted. You could always download the radio file for your device and flash it via odin. After a quick google search it seems you aren't alone. A lot of people have been posting and complaining about the Tab 4. Some people have said they flashed the radio firmware and all was good. Others said they called and got Samsung to replace the device.